# FaultContract<T> - what does it means?

Tags: wcf, faultcontract

I should create wcf service that returns data about users, the interface and DataContract is below:

```
[ServiceContract]
public interface IUserInfoProvider{
[FaultContract<UserNotFound>]
public UserInfo GetUserInfo(Guid userId)}

[DataContract]
public class UserInfo
{
     [DataMember] public Guid UserId { get; set; } 
     [DataMember] public bool? AdvertisingOptIn { get; set; } 
     [DataMember] public string CountryIsoCode { get; set; }
     [DataMember] public DateTime DateModified { get; set; }
     [DataMember] public string Locale { get; set; }
}
```

I have no special client for service - requests (get, post) runs from fiddler or rest plugin for browser.

Please, describe how to implement [FaultContract<>] in my case, i saw examples with [FaultContract(typeof(UserNotFound))] but never seen [FaultContract<>]

Comment: I've never seen `FaultContract<T>` and I don't see it on MSDN either.  Maybe `UserNotFound` is a defined FaultException?

Comment: Unfortunately i have no any additional info about it, it should be a fault that called when user not found in repository

Answer (score 0):

Sorry about the late answer, but I faced something similar and I would like to share what I've found:

FaultContract is possible: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff650547.aspx

From MSDN:

> To support the use of custom faults, WCF services use the
>   FaultContractAttribute to formally specify faults that can be returned
>   from a service operation. Types specified in a FaultContractAttribute
>   must be serializable as DataContract,SerializableAttribute, or
>   ISerializable. When a FaultException is thrown using a custom fault
>   defined in FaultContract, client applications can also catch these
>   specific faults using the FaultException generic type.

Example:

```
throw new FaultException<InvalidNameFault>(fault, "Invalid Name!");
```